# protected method vs protected property

Tags: java, inheritance, visibility

Subclasses need to be able to use the seeded random number generator.

What are the pros and cons of using

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
  protected Random rnd;

  public AbstractClass(long seed) {
    rnd = new Random(seed);
  }
}
```

versus

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
  private Random rnd;

  public AbstractClass(long seed) {
    rnd = new Random(seed);
  }

  protected Random getRnd() {
    return rnd;
  }

  protected Random setRnd(Random rnd) {
    this.rnd = rnd;
  }
}
```

Comment: you should make `rnd` `final` anyway.

Comment: You could have that in the first case too by making your field final.

Comment: @luk2302 good point, thank you for pointing that out. I edited my question (bad practice, sorry) to ask the question I was actually more interested in.

Comment: making a no-op method - the getter - protected is one of the many ways to make your code unmaintainable

Answer (score 0):

`protected` members are part of the **public** API. That is, they are completely visible to developers that come along at a later point in time (possibly years later) and write a subclass. They can even override the methods and make them `public` (visibility widening is valid, visibility narrowing isn't).

Therefore, `protected` fields should be avoided in much the same way as avoiding `public` fields: they prohibit future extensions that change the class invariants or behavior.

For example, what if you need lazy instantiation or thread-local objects to be returned? With a `protected` field none of this is possible. It's debatable whether protected fields are the best solution, though<sup>[*citation needed*]</sup>.

(Effective Java, items 13 & 17)

Comment: So `protected` members are better than `protected` properties...

Comment: Fields and methods are both members. 'Properties' are things stored in the object and are always fields, but can either be accessible fields or private fields with getter/setter methods. Anyway, public/protected methods are better than Fields is what I'm saying.